# Is the name identifier claim of a given ClaimPrincipal provided to an Azure Function the same across different applications?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, claims-based-identity

I have an application built on Azure Functions.

My users can use Facebook, Google and Microsoft as a Identity Providers as my application has been registered in each of these providers.

My Azure Functions are being given a `ClaimPrincipal` instance each time they are called. As part of the claims, I have the `nameidentifier` claim that I can use to identify a given user.

**Question**

If user `A` uses my application and is being assigned the `nameidentifier` `sid:123456`, does the same user gets assigned the same `nameidentifier` if (s)he uses a different* application?

*By different, I mean an application that has been developed by another company that has its own registration in the identity providers.*

Answer (score 0):

Name identifiers can be anything; an email address or a Kerberos principal name are common, every-day examples of such information. They do not always equal the username.

you could have a NameID coming back from your IdP as something completely unrelated to the username.

To answer your same question, it all depends on what identity providers you hook the service providers up to. More than likely, it sounds like what you want is multiple identity providers that give back the same NameID format.

In SAML 2.0, you can specify what formats the NameID can come back as so you can have a common pattern across identity providers and prevent having logic to parse out each of the NameIDs that could come back.

The NameID is what the IDP application provides. It is what your application validates on the return of the information from IDP.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be "openid" claim in tokens from each OpenID identity providers. It is UUID, so it's definitely unique value which you can use to differentiate users.